# Is it possible for django-rest-framework view to be called without a request object?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've inherited a Django code base using Django REST Framework that has many views that check for the existence of a `request` argument at the top, like this:

```
class ExampleViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    def create(self, request):
        if not request:
            return Response(status=404)
```

This doesn't seem logical to me as I don't understand how the method can be called without a request object.  I'm inclined to remove it since I haven't been able to find any documentation of this idiom.  Is there some purpose I'm missing?

Comment: The [examples from the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) use that idiom too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular if statement is indeed probably useless; you are right that the method can never be called without a request. The only exception would be if some other methods called this method directly, passing an empty or falsey value for the request parameter, but that does seem unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

They are required. This is how [Django processes the urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request).
You'll likely have an issue if you remove it as other part of the code expects this argument.

Comment: I think you and @Bakuriu both misunderstood my question.  I'm referring to the `if not request` method body, not the argument itself.

Comment: indeed. This statement is likely there for unit testing purpose by someone that doesn't want to forge a fake request.